# How to get resource path for PNG files from Bundle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to get a resource path of image files added to the project. The following code works fine for `jpeg` files. But it gives nil for `PNG` files. The name of the images are correct and added to the project.

Image files are added with the `puppy.png` and `car.jpeg` names.

```
let carPathURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "car", ofType: "jpeg") // Gives right path
let puppyPathURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "puppy", ofType: "png") // Gives nil
```

Below is the screenshot of the Application bundle contents.

[image: Application bundle contents screenshot]

The screenshot for the project is below showing the added files.

[image: Project screenshot]

Why it is giving nil for PNG files? How to get the resource path for PNG files?

Comment: In the code above, you're setting carPathURL but converting imagePathURL. The code sample is a bit confusing. Which line gives nil, the second or third line of code?

Comment: @Marcy, thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected the question. Second-line gives nil.

Comment: Where is `puppy.png` in the above screen snapshot?

Comment: @Rob, Yes it's not there, but why? I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Does iOS treat png files differently than jpg?

Comment: @Rob, I've edited the question with an updated screenshot of the project. Image files are added.

Comment: Perhaps the "Add to Targets" was not checked when you dragged the file into your project.

Comment: @Marcy, I'm pretty sure it is added to the target.

Answer (score 1):

If extension is uppercased (ie, PNG, not png) you have to specify this explicitly

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "puppy", ofType: "PNG")
```

Comment: Good point. I just tried both "png" and "PNG", the result is still nil.

Comment: @Shubham, are you sure then that you added this image to tested target? Open built application bundle content in Finder and look if the image there?

Comment: Yes, it is added to the target. and it also presents under Copy Bundle Resources section.

Comment: @Shubham, I believe in miracles, but not here )). Would you attach to the question screenshot of your application bundle content by "Show Package Contents" in Finder?

Comment: Yes I looked into that. And png file was not there.